# cannot download image from mongolab [Parse server on Heroku]

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, mlab, parse-server

I have implemented a simple instagram clone app using Parse source code on Heroku with Mongodb add-on. I have some images and messages posted on DB and when I try to retrieve the images and their corresponding messages, I only get the messages, not the images. Here are the code and error:

Code:

```
  query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (posts, err) -> Void in

               if let posts = posts {

                   for post in posts {

                        self.messages.append(post["message"]! as! String)
                        self.images.append(post["imageFile"]! as! PFFile)
                            self.usernames.append(self.users[post["userId"] as! String]!)
                            self.tableView.reloadData()

                        }
                    }
                })
```

....

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("postCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! instaPostCell

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    images[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (d, error ) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: d!) {
                cell.postedImage.image = downloadedImage
            }

       }else {
                if let error = error {
                print("error: \(error.userInfo["error"]!)")
            }
       }


    }
```

Error:
ParseStarterProject-Swift[65068:8486166] [Error]: unsupported URL (Code: 100, Version: 1.12.0)
error: unsupported URL

Note that the app retrieves the PFFiles but when it calls the getDataInBackgroundWithBlock an "unsupported URL" errors gets thrown. Also, the client code seems to be ok, as I tested the client app connected to an original Parse server ( used my instructor appId and masterkey) and it worked great.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The purpose of this site is for programming related questions. So that means that if their is a problem with your code we need to see what you have done in order to point out the problem and solution. Their is no code here, so you need to post your code where the problem occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the guideline. I added the codes.

Comment: Are you using a file adapter to store your files or do you store then in the mondoDB file grid? If you use a file adapter maybe the URL to the adapter in index.js is invalid?